# How to make Networkx produce GML file with sorted nodes

Tags: python, graph, igraph, networkx

I have the following codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import networkx as nx
def main():
    """docstring for main"""
    outerdict = {"A":["a1","a2","a3"], "B":["b1","b2","b3","b5","b6", "b7"], "C":["c2","c3"], "D":["d1","d2","d3"]}
    keynode = "Z"

    colorlist = [ "#beaed4", "#fdc086", "#ffff99", "#386cb0","#f0027f"]
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_node(keynode,graphics={"fill":"#7fc97f","w":27,"h":27, "d":27})
    for i,ky in enumerate(outerdict):
        nodes = outerdict[ky]
        nodecol = colorlist[i]
        print ky, nodecol
        for node in nodes:
            G.add_node(node,graphics={"fill":nodecol,"w":27,"h":27,"d":27})
            G.add_edge(keynode, node, value = 10)

    outfile = "test.gml"
    nx.write_gml(G,outfile)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It produces the following GML file:

```
graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "b6"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#ffff99"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "a1"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#beaed4"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "b5"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#ffff99"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 3
    label "a3"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#beaed4"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 4
    label "a2"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#beaed4"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 5
    label "b7"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#ffff99"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 6
    label "b1"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#ffff99"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 7
    label "b2"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#ffff99"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 8
    label "b3"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#ffff99"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 9
    label "c3"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#fdc086"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 10
    label "c2"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#fdc086"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 11
    label "Z"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#7fc97f"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 12
    label "d2"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#386cb0"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 13
    label "d3"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#386cb0"
    ]
  ]
  node [
    id 14
    label "d1"
    graphics [ 
      h 27
      d 27
      w 27
      fill "#386cb0"
    ]
  ]
  edge [
    source 0
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 1
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 2
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 3
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 4
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 5
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 6
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 7
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 8
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 9
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 10
    target 11
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 11
    target 12
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 11
    target 13
    value 10
  ]
  edge [
    source 11
    target 14
    value 10
  ]
]
```

Notice that the node are not in order. For example `a1` is in between `b1` and `b5`. This makes the plot looks like this:

[image]

What I expect the graph is to sequentially order according to the loop and initial data structure `outderdict`. So that yellow nodes will go together sequentially with other yellows etc.

How can I sort the GML file using Networkx? Other solution (e.g. Igraph) as long as within Python framework is welcomed.

Comment: Could you not use an ordereddict instead? The key order will be random using a standard dict, otherwise you'd have to sort the values in the dict first before adding the nodes

Comment: @EdChum: Each color (yellow, blue, purple,etc) correspond to a key. It doesn't have to be ordered. What we want is the **members** of each key should be ordered together,e.g. all yellow nodes shouldn't be alternated with purple nodes. Since the members are contained in **list** it should by default in order. But somehow `networkx` upon creating the GML disregard the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordered graph data structure is available in NetworkX since inclusion on Jan 1 2015.  The OrderedGraph class will output nodes and edges from the NetworkX data structure in the order they are added.
You'll need to get the latest development version at https://github.com/networkx/networkx/ for the following to work.

```
import networkx as nx
outerdict = {"A":["a1","a2","a3"], "B":["b1","b2","b3","b5","b6", "b7"], "C":["c2","c3"], "D":["d1","d2","d3"]}
keynode = "Z"
colorlist = [ "#beaed4", "#fdc086", "#ffff99", "#386cb0","#f0027f"]
G = nx.OrderedGraph()
G.add_node(keynode,graphics={"fill":"#7fc97f","w":27,"h":27, "d":27})
for i,ky in enumerate(outerdict):
    nodes = outerdict[ky]
    nodecol = colorlist[i]
    print ky, nodecol
    for node in nodes:
        G.add_node(node,graphics={"fill":nodecol,"w":27,"h":27,"d":27})
        G.add_edge(keynode, node, value = 10)
outfile = "test.gml"
nx.write_gml(G,outfile)
```

Note that your 'outerdict' data structure might appear in a different order than you have initialized it when you loop over 'enumerate(outerdict)'.  If the order of the nodes "A","B","C", and "D" matters to you then you will need to change how they are added to the graph to insure they get inserted in that order.